# Create a walk cycle animation Javascript/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create a walk cycle that on every scroll, the image should change to the next one.

I try with:

```html
<img src="" id="walk" />
```

```
var imageArr = ["img/walk1.png", "img/walk2.png", "img/walk3.png", "img/walk4.png"];

        function animate() {
            windowScrollCount = $(this).scrollTop();
            animationFrame = (windowScrollCount / 8);
            animationFrame = Math.floor(animationFrame % imageArr.length);
            $('#walk').attr("src", imageArr[animationFrame]);
        }
```

If I scroll the page, the animation is not completed.

My idea for walk cycle is exactly this: http://www.rleonardi.com/interactive-resume/

I hope somebody has an idea

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, take this very bland example and instead of writing out the index, perform setting the src attribute as you do in the example.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var fullheight = $(document).height();
  var progress = window.pageYOffset/fullheight;
  var subimagecount = 8;
  var subimage = Math.floor(progress * subimagecount)
  $('.counter').text(subimage);
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/axpQap

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example you need to add the animate function to a scroll handler and also initialize it on document load:

```
const imageArr = ["img/walk1.png", "img/walk2.png", "img/walk3.png", "img/walk4.png"];

function animate() {
  windowScrollCount = $(this).scrollTop();
  animationFrame = (windowScrollCount / 8);
  animationFrame = Math.floor(animationFrame % imageArr.length);
  $('#walk').attr("src", imageArr[animationFrame]);
}

$('#container').on('scroll', animate);

$(function() {
  animate();
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zr1mLhj/2/) with an number example.

Answer (score 0):

If I scroll the counter, can stop on 1 or 2 or 3 or 4. My goal is that in every scroll, the function start from 1 and finish to 4.

Ex.:
SCROLL --> [1,2,3,4,1]
but now
SCROLL --> [1,2] or [1,2,3]